# Rails paperclip doesn't display uploaded images from Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I uploaded images to Amazon S3, but they're not displaying.

I get this error:

```html
<Error>
<Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
<Message>
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
</Message>
<Bucket>cb123</Bucket>
<Endpoint>cb123.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
<RequestId>870BC2E8570EF4E7</RequestId>
<HostId>
yuBkeXxftr7O9Ib0SasFTq8Hlvgc7hkhx9VMr+VwRL74qSDgJ9rqMgEU9noRIQe/
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Here are my settings:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "400x400#", small: "250x250#", :url =>':s3_domain_url', :path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename' }
```

thank you!

Comment: Did you followed all this steps correctly? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your `application.rb` or to the config file for each environment:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_host_name => 's3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => 'your bucket',
    :access_key_id => 'your access-key-id',
    :secret_access_key => 'your secret-access-key'
  }, 
  :url =>':s3_domain_url',
  :path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
}
```

You can then remove the `:url` and `:path` config from your model.

Comment: I added this to  'application.rb' and removed from my model, but there is still the same error. Maybe the issue is that i set the region of my bucket to  Frankfurt?

Comment: it seems paperclip has issues with buckets outside of US but these settings are supposed to fix it. Did you restart your server to make sure the new config took effect?

Comment: also, what version of the aws gem are you using? is it `gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'`

Comment: Try adding this (will update answer): `:s3_host_name => 's3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'` Make sure to repeat the upload process once you have this configured

Answer (score 3):

Adding my code here because the syntax has changed slightly since the last answer.

You need your S3_host_name added to your config.paperclip_defaults in config/environments/development.rb and also production.db.

Here is the full code snippet, change us-west-2 to whatever region your bucket is on:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_host_name: 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also add this to your model where your `has_attached_file` method present:

```
:url =>':s3_domain_url'
```